# AWS - Create new instance from AMI, but lost keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, key-pair

I have an AMI that I created a few weeks ago. I want to launch a new AWS EC2 instance and provide that AMI as the image. Problem is, I can't ssh into that box now.

I have tried to attach a new key pair when launching the new instance, but it's as if the configuration of the SSH keys on the box is ignoring my newly attached key pair.

Is there a way to overcome this issue?

I know my new key pair works, I've tested it on a totally blank new instance and I can SSH in just fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the security group for your EC2 instance allowing connections on port 22 from your IP address?

Comment: Not port 22 no, I use a different port, but the security group does allow it. Networking shouldn't be an issue though. I can reach the instance, it just says "Permission denied (public key)".

Comment: What linux distro is the AMI? What is the user did you try to ssh in as?

Comment: Distro is Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: As of ~2018/2019, you can login via Sessions Manager or EC2 Instance Connect. With these you can login without a keypair, allowing you to upload a new public key to the instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keypair is only copied to the Amazon EC2 instance the first time that the disk is booted. Since you have already booted from that disk (or a disk from which the image was made), it will not copy the keypair again.

You will need to **copy a new keypair** to the `/home/ec2-user/.ssh` directory. This can be done by attaching the EBS volume to a different instance:

- Stop the instance (`Instance 1`)
- Detach the EBS volume (make a note of the device identifier, eg `/dev/xvda`)
- Attach the EBS volume to another Linux instance (`Instance 2`)
- Edit the `/home/edc2-user/.ssh/authorized_keys` file and insert your desired public key
- Detach the EBS volume from `Instance 1`, re-attach it to `Instance 2`
- Start `Instance 1` and ssh to it using your new keypair

See documentation: [Connecting to Your Linux Instance if You Lose Your Private Key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#replacing-lost-key-pair)

Comment: It's an ubuntu 14.04 distro, so not sure if it will work the same as Amazon Linux. Will have to test it out. Thanks anyway.