# ec2 instance access failed due to change in owner

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, centos

When I login to the server, but 22 is already open for all upcoming connections still getting error as below,

```
ssh Server_Name
ssh: connect to host Server-IP port 22: Connection refused
```

I misleadingly change the the owner of the system and change root privileges with jenkins. So, right now I could not able to log into the system and `port 22 is closed` it's throwing the error.

I understood the error issue occurred because of wrong fstab file and wrong editing to sshd conf(Not sure). And, the directory of authorized_keys been messed up. I tried this [solution](http://dltj.org/article/ec2-fix-authorized_keys/) but not working

I tried accessing via public DNS, via private IP address, detaching and re-attaching volumes driver after attaching it to other instance(but, once I attached to it, I could not able to ssh into that instance), etc. but no luck. Also, tried login with Jenkins user still not working. But, jenkins is still running fine on the server and I could access the Jenkins Dashboard and run the shell onto my instance. But, if I try any sudo command, it shows sudo: [effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250560/centos-error-sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-sudo-installed-setuid-root)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Questions

- Is there any way to get back my instance port 22 running fine as before ?
- Is there a way I can run the sudo commands using Jenkins user by creating the job(By running the shell) inside Jenkins ?

I could trace on the IP which clearly shows port 22 is closed and I could not do anything because of it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: An old article, but it has the right general steps: [How to Recover an Unreachable Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein : Thanks. I tried all the steps but didn't work for me.

Comment: Similar to: [AWS - Create new instance from AMI, but lost keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42309884/174777)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein: I already try this too, but could not be able to access the instance after reattaching(after copying the new public key)... thanks a lot Sir